# Can the SonicWall SRA Virtual Appliance (SonicOS SSL-VPN 6.0.0.0) use Gmail for SMTP?

Tags: vpn, smtp, g-suite, sonicwall

I have a SonicWall SRA Virtual Appliance running **SonicOS SSL-VPN v6.0.0.0**. I need to update the SMTP settings (used for one-time passwords) because we're switching ISPs and will no longer have access to our old ISP's SMTP service.

Since we use GSuite for email and a bunch of other stuff, I'm trying to get the Gmail SMTP working with the SonicWall, but not having any luck.

***Does anyone know if SonicOS SSL-VPN 6.0.0.0 is incompatible with Gmail SMTP?***

All 3 versions of [Gmail's SMTP](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) do not work:

- **Restricted Gmail SMTP server `aspmx.l.google.com`:**

  - We can't use this option because we're sending to non-Gmail/GSuite accounts (eg: 1234561234@tmomail.net).

    - SonicWall logs "Error sending one-time password: SMTP server does not allow relaying to external domains". *This is expected behavior.*
  - Sending to an @gmail.com address works.
  - Sending to a GSuite address works.
- **Gmail SMTP server `smtp.gmail.com`:**

  - The SonicWall gets stuck at "Attempting to send OTP to me@gsuite-domain.com".
  - Tried both SSL/465 and TLS/587.
  - No error codes are returned, no timeout message.
- **G Suite SMTP relay `smtp-relay.gmail.com`:**

  - The SonicWall gets stuck at "Attempting to send OTP to me@gsuite-domain.com".
  - Tried SSL/465, TLS/587, and no encryption (port 25)

For the GSuite SMTP relay, I've gone through and added our public static IPs to the GSuite settings [per the docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491). I've also verified that the GSuite SMTP relay works with other appliances.

---

#### Idea:

Is the SonicOS silently truncating or otherwise modifying the password entered for smtp auth?

- I notice that the "mail password" display only shows 4 characters after saving, but this could just be a display thing. Our password is long, but not excessively so in my opinion.
- Our SMTP password has some special characters in it, but nothing out of the ordinary (eg: `!@#$%^&*`)

---

#### Other possibly relevant info

Our perimeter firewall is a SonicWall NSA 2600 running SonicOS Enhanced 6.1.2.3 (this one likes `smtp.gmail.com`). The SRA is a virtual machine running on VMWare ESXi 5.5 with a static private (192.168) IP address. The NSA 2600 has the following NAT policies:

```
Source                            | Destination
Original        -> Translated     | Original       -> Translated
---------------    ---------------|---------------    ---------------
Any             -> Original       | SSL-VPN_Public -> SSL-VPN_Private
SSL-VPN_Private -> SSL-VPN_Public | Any            -> Original
```

With this NAT, the GSuite SMTP relay *should* accept things that come from the `SSL-VPN_Public` IP, right?

I'm currently looking into upgrading the SRA to see if that helps, but it looks like it'll be a bit of work because the SRA was replaced by the SMA 500V.

Our support with SonicWall (for the SRA) expired in 2014... :-(

Comment: You might consider using a service like SendGrid instead. SendGrid allows you to send up to 100 emails a day for free.

Comment: Yeah, someone on Reddit suggested [DNSExit](www.dnsexit.com). I'm looking into that now, but appear to be running into similar issues.